# Remove div using jQuery not working for dynamically added div

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, onclick

I have added div on a button click, i want the user to be able to delete the added item form the list by clicking "X" which is an anchor, but on its click no event is triggered, Here is my code, I have even tried binding but nothing seems to work.

```
(function ( $ ) { 
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".btn-add").on("click",function() {
var $row = $(this).closest("tr"); // Find the row
var $text = $row.find(".this-name").text(); // Find the text

// Let's test it out
$('#col2').append('<div class="item"><p>'+$text+'</p><a href="#" class="delete-button">X</a></div>');
});

});

$("document").on('click','.delete-button', function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 alert('yes');
 $(this).closest('.item').remove();
});

}( jQuery ));
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: this is `document` not `"document"`

Comment: Could you please add relevant `html` so that we can replicate this?

Comment: Syed - your edit of the question removed the dot but didn't remove the quotes.

Comment: quotes were the issue, I feel so Dumb. its working fine now thanks @AmeyaDeshpande
sometimes u only need a pair of eyes of someone else to solve the error :)

Comment: For a moment there, I was going to say, "You binded a document click with a target that's not yet inserted into the DOM in an anonymous function."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: onClick="$(this).parent().remove();"

```
(function ( $ ) { 
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(".btn-add").on("click",function() {
         var $row = $(this).closest("tr"); // Find the row
         var $text = $row.find(".this-name").text(); // Find the text
         // Let's test it out
         $('#col2').append('<div class="item"><p>'+$text+'</p><a href="#" class="delete-button" onClick="$(this).parent().remove();">X</a></div>');
     });
});
$(document).on('click','.delete-button', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('yes');
    $(this).closest('.item').remove();
});
}( jQuery ));
```

Comment: Observe that I have added Onlcik code for anchor "X" itself.